# Keyboard not responding after login. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I updated to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and now after I login the keyboard is locked.  The mouse will move about the desktop but buttons also do not work.

In one of the posts I read it suggested keyboard driver breaks after major upgrade and to run

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

I did but the system stated system was running latest version   "version(1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and my keyboard is working now-- someone suggested in another post that turning on the screen keyboard, turning on caps lock and then turning it back off would fix it and I think that's what did it.